# Writing variables as subscripts in math mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to plot some data, using a for loop to plot distributions. Now I want to label those distributions according to the loop counter as the subscript in math notation. This is where I am with this at the moment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

mean = [10,12,16,22,25]
variance = [3,6,8,10,12]
x = np.linspace(0,40,1000)
for i in range(4):
    sigma = np.sqrt(variance[i])
    y = mlab.normpdf(x,mean[i],sigma)
    plt.plot(x,y,label=$v_i$) # where i is the variable i want to use to label. I should also be able to use elements from an array, say array[i] for the same.
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("P(X)")
plt.legend()
plt.axvline(x=15, ymin=0, ymax=1,ls='--',c='black')    
plt.show()
```

This doesn't work, and I can't keep the variable between the $  $ signs of the math notation, as it is interpreted as text. Is there a way to put the variable in the $ $ notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The original question has been edited, this answer has been updated to reflect this.*

When trying to work with LaTeX formatting in matplotlib you must use raw strings, denoted by `r""`.

The code given below will iterate over `range(4)` and plot using `i'th` mean and variance (as you originally have done). It will also set the `label` for each plot using `label=r'$v_{}$'.format(i+1)`. This [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) simply replaces the `{}` with whatever is called inside `format`, in this case `i+1`. In this way you can automate the labels for your plots.

I have removed the `plt.axvline(...)`, `plt.xlabel(...)` and `plt.ylabel(...)` out of the `for` loop as you only need to call it once. I've also removed the `plt.legend()` from the `for` loop for the same reason and have removed its arguments. If you supply the keyword argument `label` to `plt.plot()` then you can label your plots individually as you plot them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

mean = [10,12,16,22,25]
variance = [3,6,8,10,12]

x = np.linspace(0,40,1000)

for i in range(4):
    sigma = np.sqrt(variance[i])
    y = mlab.normpdf(x,mean[i],sigma)
    plt.plot(x,y, label=r'$v_{}$'.format(i+1))

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("P(X)")        
plt.axvline(x=15, ymin=0, ymax=1,ls='--',c='black')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: But the problem persists, as I still cannot use variables inside the math-text mode. In this case it was numbers 1-4. It could also be text, say e^x, e^y, and so on, where 'x', 'y', 'z', etc. are the variables to be placed in the math mode. Would you know, if such usage is possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean unfortunately, are you saying that the math text mode is not working? Or are you saying that you don't want to choose the labels but instead would like it to automatically select the variable that you have plotted? If so, that is not possible no.

Comment: As you have modified your question I have edited my answer now to take this into account. I now believe that this answer answers your question.

Comment: Of course, the .format, didn't occur to me at all to use this. Thank you, and +1 for linking the documentation page. :) I have made an edit by removing the p = [], as it not required anymore.

Comment: why doesn't this work when the subscript has multiple letters? only the first letter is displayed as a subscript

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out that you edited your question based on my answer. However, you;re still not quite there. If you want to do it the way I think you want to code it, it should be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

mean = [10, 12, 16, 22, 25]
variance = [3, 6, 8, 10, 12]
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 1000)
for i in range(4):
    sigma = np.sqrt(variance[i])
    y = mlab.normpdf(x, mean[i], sigma)
    plt.plot(x, y, label = "$v_{" + str(i) + "}$") 
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("P(X)")

plt.legend()
plt.axvline(x = 15, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, ls = '--', c = 'black')  

plt.show()
```

This code generates the following figure:
[image]
In case you want the first plot start with v_1 instead of v_0 all you need to change is `str(i+1)`. This way the subscripts are 1, 2, 3, and 4 instead of 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Hope this helps!