# Python print, string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, string-formatting

If I have a variable and want to use the string formatting, I would use:

```
print 'r_0 =%02f ' %(variable1)
```

which works fine. However I would like to use "math mode" inside `print`. 
i.e.

```
print r'$r_{0}=%02f \pm %02f$' %(variable1,variable2)
```

The above doesn't seem to work. It just prints the values of `variable1` and `variable2` correctly, but it doesn't print `r_0` and `\pm` as it should. i.e. it prints

```
$r_{0}=18.966 \pm 0.424698$
```

**My question is, how to make the subscript `(r_{0})` and `\pm` work!**

Comment: As far as I understand it seems that you believe that `print 'r_0 =%02f ' %(variable1)` will assign value `variable1` to variable `r_0` ?

Comment: @massiou: No, the values are assigned correctly. That is not my question. My question is, how to make the subscripts and \pm work!

Comment: What do you mean by `make the subscript (r_{0}) and \pm work!` ??

Comment: @massiou: actually, in math mode ($$), `\pm` should give me `plus or minus` and `r_{0}` should give me an `r with 0 as the subscript`

Comment: @user3397243, that isn't a feature of Python string formatting. Can you describe in what context those features do exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing variables as subscripts in math mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276918/writing-variables-as-subscripts-in-math-mode)

Comment: I assume you mean ipython-notebook – as python itself has no "math mode" or any way to render MathJax/LaTeX-markup

Comment: @Robᵩ: 
 
So how do I write subscripts and other LaTeX environments in `print`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you seem to be confusing string formatting with LaTeX. You *cannot* use inline LaTeX with Python.

Comment: So how do I write subscripts and other LaTeX environments in `print`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to render a LaTeX-formatted string in a `code`-cell in ipython-notebook, you'll have to do something like this:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
display(Math(r'$r_{0}=%02f \pm %02f$' % (1, 2)))
```